# Dependent choices (DC) in ${\bf HOD}(\mathbb{R},X)$, where $X$ is a set of reals

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In *Turing invariant sets and the perfect set property*, Math. Log. Quart. **66** (2020), Hamel, Horowitz and Shelah, the authors work in ZF + DC. They claim that DC can be dispensed with, asserting:

> if $V \models {\rm ZF}\: + $ “all Turing invariant sets have the perfect set property” and $X \in V$ is a set of reals, then ${\bf HOD}(\mathbb{R},X) \models {\rm ZF} + {\rm DC}\: +$ “all Turing invariant sets have the perfect set property”.

**Question**: Why would ${\bf HOD}(\mathbb{R},X) \models {\rm DC}$, here?

For context: the paper proves: *If all Turing invariant sets have the perfect set property, then all sets of reals have the perfect set property*. It's available on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12558

Comment: Note that this implies in particular that ZF + "all Turing invariant sets (of reals) have the perfect set property" proves DC$_\mathbb{R}$, since it holds in $\mathrm{HOD}(\mathbb{R},X)$ w.r.t. the arbitrary $X$ from $V$. It follows that ZF+AD proves DC$_\mathbb{R}$. That was an open problem in the 70s/80s; has it been solved?

Comment: @Farmer S. I don't believe that problem has been solved. Hence my question. Kechris showed that, in (ℝ), AD implies DC.

Comment: Haim sometimes shows up on the site, hopefully he'll see this soon.

Comment: Though the claim is not correct as pointed out by Asaf below, the major result in the paper can be proved within $ZF$.

Comment: @喻良, yes indeed, only ZF is needed. My question was about the claim about DC in (ℝ,).

Comment: Just as a small update, I wrote Haim, he admitted the mistake was an oversight, but that it doesn't matter to the results, as @喻良 and Ramez L. Sami wrote.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila for the update! It does bring a clear end to this matter.

Comment: @喻良, I didn't realize **you** were the author of the recursion-theoretic version of the proof, and the extension to countable $\Sigma^1_1$ equivalence relations. Bravo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the "singular Solovay-style model" of John Truss from

> *Truss, John*, [**Models of set theory containing many perfect sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(74)90015-1), Ann. Math. Logic 7, 197-219 (1974). [ZBL0302.02024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.02024).

In that model the following holds:

1. $V=L(\Bbb R)$, and therefore for any set of reals, $X$, the equalities $\mathrm{HOD}(\Bbb R,X)=L(\Bbb R)=V$ hold.
2. $\sf DC$ fails, since $\omega_1$ is singular.
3. Every set of reals, Turing invariant or not, has the perfect set property.

If I understand their claim correctly, this is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I did think, at first hand, that what is stated couldn't be literally true. It would imply "ZF + AD $\vdash \text{DC}_\mathbf{R}$". Which, as far I know, is a long standing open problem. This was also noticed above. My hesitation is due to the distinguished signatures, of the paper.